# Can I write a script to take an action right before the computer is going to go to sleep?

Tags: macos, mail.app, sleep-wake, script

I think my computer is randomly not syncing email correctly with Apple Mail, but it's only a problem when it wakes from sleep.

That issue is neither here nor there. What I'd like to do is write a script / something that will quit Apple Mail if it detects that the computer is going to sleep.

Ideally, there'd be a similar process to open Apple Mail upon waking from sleep, but that's less of an issue.

I tried looking for a system event library of some kind, but all I can find is fsevents (which I don't think has anything about sleep).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a daemon like [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/). Once you’ve installed SleepWatcher (ref. the README included with it), you can run commands like the following.

```
/usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher -s /path/to/sleepscript -w /path/to/wakeupscript
```

The script

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript -e 'quit app "Mail"'
```

will quit Mail, and the script

```
#!/bin/sh
open -a /Applications/Mail.app $1
```

will open it. You can save these as `.sh` files and reference them from sleepwatcher, but ensure you run `chmod +x filename.sh` on them before you try running them. Otherwise, OS X won’t recognize them as executable.

Now, you have two options for loading sleepwatcher: you can manually run it, you can configure a LaunchAgent to do so. I like the latter, so create a file in `/Library/LaunchAgents/` named `com.custom.mailfix.plist` (the name is unimportant, but I recommend you keep the formatting, the “com” and the “plist”). The file’s contents should resemble the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.custom.mailfix.plist</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher</string>
    <string></string>
    <string>-s /path/to/sleepscript</string>
    <string>-w /path/to/wakescript</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As before, replace the script paths with paths to your shell scripts. To tell OS X to launch this agent at startup, run

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/com.custom.mailfix.plist
```

Comment: and then what? could you be bit more precise, not just a link.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to be more specific. Sorry about that!